# Binding working in XAML but not in code behind

Tags: vb.net, xaml, binding

I have 2 text boxes one named smoke alarms and one named faulty smoke alarms, I run a converter when the input changes on smoke alarms and f the value is greater than zero I show faulty smoke alarms, if not I hide it. This works if I declare the textboxes in XAML but not if I declare them in code behind. I get no errors, what am I doing wrong?

```
   <Grid>
        <ItemsControl x:Name="itemsControl" Margin="10">
            <!--<TextBox x:Name="SmokeAlarms" Width="100" FontSize="20" />
            <TextBox x:Name="FaultySmokeAlarms" Width="100" 
            Margin="0,10,0,0" FontSize="20"/>-->
        </ItemsControl>
    </Grid>

   Dim SmokeAlarms As New TextBox With {.Name = "SmokeAlarms", .Width = 200, .FontSize = 20}
    Dim FaultySmokeAlarms As New TextBox With {.Name = "FaultySmokeAlarms", .Width = 200, .FontSize = 20}



  Public Sub New()

        ' This call is required by the designer.
        InitializeComponent()

        ' Add any initialization after the InitializeComponent() call.
        itemsControl.Items.Add(SmokeAlarms)
        itemsControl.Items.Add(FaultySmokeAlarms)

    End Sub

    Private Sub MainWindow_Loaded(sender As Object, e As RoutedEventArgs) Handles Me.Loaded
        Try
            Dim b As New Binding
            b.Converter = New IntegerToVisibilityConverter
            b.ElementName = "SmokeAlarms"
            b.Mode = BindingMode.TwoWay
            b.UpdateSourceTrigger = UpdateSourceTrigger.PropertyChanged
            b.Path = New PropertyPath("Text")
            BindingOperations.SetBinding(FaultySmokeAlarms, VisibilityProperty, b)
        Catch ex As Exception
        End Try
    End Sub
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Change the .ElementName to .Source for code behind.